# PHP , Laravel , Model , Sql

Tags: php, laravel, model

[image: my table proverbe]

[image: My table proverbe_jour]

i have a bug with my laravel project when i try to insert a new object in a table

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ... "theme") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) returning "id"
>   ^ (SQL: insert into "proverbe_jour" ("id_proverbe", "date", "proverbe", "signification", "ethnie", "pays", "theme") values (62, 2017-06-11 01:05:31, Couvert aux épaules mais nu aux hanches., Qui tape sur un panier couvert de suie reçoit la suie sur sa tête., Basonge, Congo, Bon sens) returning "id")

**This is my controller**

```
 <?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\jour;
use App\Proverbe;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


    public function rien(){

        return view('welcome');

    }

    public function jour($id){


        $proverbe = Proverbe::where('id' , '=' ,$id)->first();




        $proverbedujour  = new jour();
        $proverbedujour->id_proverbe = $id;
        $date = new \DateTime(null);
        $proverbedujour->date = $date;
        $proverbedujour->proverbe =$proverbe->proverbe;
        $proverbedujour->signification =$proverbe->signification;
        $proverbedujour->ethnie =$proverbe->ethnie;
        $proverbedujour->pays =$proverbe->pays;
        $proverbedujour->theme =$proverbe->theme;
        $proverbedujour->save();




    }

    public function listproverbe(){


        $proverbes = Proverbe::paginate(10);



        return view('listproverbe')->with('proverbes' , $proverbes);

    }



    public function valide(Request $request){
        $parameters = $request->except('_token');





        if(isset($parameters['proverbe'])  &&  isset($parameters['signification'])    &&  isset($parameters['theme']) && isset($parameters['pays'])){


            Proverbe::create($parameters);
            return redirect()->Route('home')->with('success',' proverb well added ');



        }else {

            return redirect()->Route('home')->with('error','Please complete all the fields');
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: Please include your migration file for the proverbe_jour table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i think error is here :

```
$proverbe = Proverbe::where('id' , '=' ,$id)->first();
```

You are fetching a column(id) which doesn't exist, assuming u have id_proverbe as your primary key.

can u show me your table structure or migration file?

Comment: i include a picture of my table proverbe

Comment: which picture? try $proverbe = Proverbe::where('id_proverbe' , '=' ,$id)->first(); instead. replace id with id_proverbe

Comment: i have included two picture of my two table

Comment: did u try what i suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your migration, probably in the table `proverbe_jour` does not have the column `id`.

Comment: i have not a migration , i am connecting to a database that already existed.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended by Laravel to use unified attributes all along your app classes, so instead of altering between `id` and `id_proverbe`, use `id` for both.